# Subtract one month from Datetime.Today

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `DateTimePicker` in which I allow user to select month previous to the current year.

The problem is, that if the date is 1st January, it can't calculate the December month of last year in the way I am doing it now.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

var lastmonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month - 1, 1);
if (qs == "")
{
    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = lastmonth;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = lastmonth;
}
else
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(qs);

    dateTimePicker1.Value = dt;
    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = lastmonth;
}
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Just substract a month by 'adding` -1:

```
var lastmonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
```

See the MSDN documentation on [`DateTime.AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this. let's say i have 3 filter buttons which are suppose to get data from previous 1, 6 and 9 months, it looks a bit ugly (is it just me or someone else thinks the same?) to have bunch of minus numbers being fed through the AddMonths method. and also having magic numbers in the code? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Patrick got it. To build on his answer and improve error handling (if there's a possibility that `qs` could be an invalid date string), you might do something like:

```
DateTime qsValue;

dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);

dateTimePicker1.Value = (DateTime.TryParse(qs, out qsValue))
    ? qsValue
    : dateTimePicker1.MaxDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you, like Adil H. Raza, don't like to have negative numbers in your code, you could also make an extension method:

```
public static DateTime SubtractMonths(this DateTime dt, int months) => dt.AddMonths(-months);
```

And use it like

```
var lastmonth = DateTime.Today.SubtractMonths(1);
```