# Subtracting DateTime Months using .AddMonths(-1) does nothing?

Tags: c#, datetime

This is my code, and I don't understand why it doesn't work.  This is literal copy pasta `[edit] from my own code base`; there should be no hidden complexities `[edit] from elsewhere in the code`.  [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777001/subtract-one-month-from-datetime-today/27777030) implies that this should work.  What am I missing?

```
DateTime billDate = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1);            // March 1st, 2020
MessageBox.Show($"billdate month {billDate.Month}");     // billdate month 3
billDate.AddMonths(-1);                                  // subtract a month
MessageBox.Show($"month after change {billDate.Month}"); // month after change 3
```

I expect the month to decrease to 2.  Why doesn't it?

Comment: You have to `var newDate = billDate.AddMonths(x)`

Comment: Quoting the documentation: Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of months to the value of this instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[AddMonths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=netframework-4.8) returns a new `DateTime` object; it doesn't mutate the existing one.  Try:

```
billDate = billDate.AddMonths(-1);
```

Comment: Indeed, a `DateTime` is immutable.